# ORing LINQ Query in linq to object, built using expression trees

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I want same field combine with ORs and between two diffferent fileds with AND.

ex -  If they have the same Field value, those all ORed. This allows us to say "State", "eq", "CA", OR "State", "eq", "TX" AND "FirstName", "eq", "John".

```
(State==CA || State==TX) AND FirstName==John)
```

Comment: people.Where(p => p.State == "CA" || p.State = "TX").Where(p => p.FirstName == "John")

Comment: Why are you building the query using expressions if it's a linq to objects query?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this:

#### 1. Chain `Where()s`

You can chain together two `Where()` statements, the first one with the OR and the second satisfying the AND. This can get to be really useful when you have a query that you're programmatically/dynamically building:

```
var output = input
                .Where(a => a.State == "CA" || a.State == "TX")
                .Where(a => a.FirstName == "John");
```

Since the `Where()` filters are run in series, the effect is a logical AND of the conditions in each.

#### 2. Parenthetical Logic

You can also just use parentheses to dictate the order of operation:

```
var output = input
                .Where(a => (a.State == "CA" || a.State == "TX") 
                             && a.FirstName == "John");
```